# Display ReST response in Angular page from Restangular service call

Tags: json, angularjs, restangular

I have a simple angular page:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <td>{{client.email}}</td>
    <td>{{client.role}}</td>
</tr>
```

In my angular controller i have:

```
$scope.clients= Restangular.all('clients').getList().$object;
```

I'm expecting to see the results in the page, but i do not.
I tested the service call with a browser plugin, and it works fine(I get JSON back of the clients).

Any idea why this is not working?

If I change me controller to the following, I can see the values of the client:

```
Restangular.all('clients').getList().then(
    function(client) {
        for (var i = 0; i < client.length; i++) {
            console.log("==>: " + client[i].email + ", role: " + client[i].role);
        }
    }
);
```

Do I need to use this second way (with the promise) and build my own "clients" array so that it will be displayed on the angular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Restangular.all('clients').getList().then(
    function(clients) {
    $scope.clients = clients;
    });
```

Assuming that you have email and role in your response.